# Select rows with categoryId belongs to 2 or more values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this :

[image]

I want to find the courseId where the courseId belongs to 2 or more categoryIds. E.g. If I give the categoryId to be 18112 and 21115 then it should only give the courseIds - 18602 & 21101.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Group by the `courseId` and select only those having these 2 `categoryId`s

```
select courseId
from your_table
where categoryId in (18112,21115)
group by courseId
having count(distinct categoryId) = 2
```

Comment: >=2, not =2, he said "2 or more then 2"

Comment: the WHERE clause selects only those 2

Answer (score 1):

```
select courseId 
from courses_categories
where categoryId in (18112,21115)
group by courseId
having count(distinct categoryId) >= 2
```

Comment: equal to 2 also needed. if so, `count(distinct categoryId) >= 2`

Answer (score 1):

`Group by` and `Having` clauses will helps you.

```
select courseId
from your_table
where categoryId in (18112,21115)
group by courseId
having count(distinct categoryId) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as below:

```
SELECT courseId
FROM table_name
WHERE categoryId IN (18112,21115)
GROUP BY courseId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT categoryId) >= 2
```